# cx_freeze doesn't make Python apps standalone

Tags: python, linux

cx_freeze makes python apps only executable. If python or neccessary modules is not installed, app doesn't open. How can i make Python 2.7 apps standalone with cx_freeze or any other app? (For Linux)

Answer (score 2):

pyinstaller works under linux and also windows / OS X, look at http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/

first simply do: pip install pyinstaller

to package your app: pyinstaller --onefile yourfile.py

Simple enough, isn't it?

Comment: Does it support tkinter ? Because i can't run it.

Comment: Should be working according to this: http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/